# Data from a user visible to other users - Django project

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm building an educational project in Django - it's a simple task manager application. The main issue I'm facing is, when I'm adding a new task, I can see 'Categories' added by different users alongside my own categories which might cause a mess in the database and confusion.

On the screenshot, 'Holidays' is displayed twice, first one added by a different user, while second one added by my user.

```
Screenshot: https://imgur.com/GiwwfXN
Models: https://github.com/jpgenari/KaTask/blob/main/tasks/models.py
Views: https://github.com/jpgenari/KaTask/blob/main/tasks/views.py
Forms: https://github.com/jpgenari/KaTask/blob/main/tasks/forms.py
```

Deployed project (no CSS applied yet): https://katask-9e69d33c7144.herokuapp.com/

I want to be able to view only categories I added myself when I'm creating or editing tasks.

Comment: In views.py when you get categorise from db filter it with as author = request.user. That's how should be filtered. ` categories = Category.Objects.filter(author = request.user)`.

Comment: Also, don't post links to code. Just post the code itself in here using code blocks. Like ```code``` .

Comment: Please *don't* post links to code: if you later change or remove the links, the question becomes invalid, and is no longer useful for other people. it also makes it harder to search for relevant content. Include the *gist* of the code into the question by [edit]ing it.